# How do I create a form that links to another form where I can then enter multiple entries associated with the first record?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

I have created a data entry form on MS Access that allows me to input details for a Venue (i,e, venue name, address, contact details etc). I am trying to create another form that will allow me to add opening times for that specific record. Is it possible to have a button within the Venue data entry form that will save that specific record once the data has been input, and then take me to another form that will allow me to specify the opening and closing times for each day of the week?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create a macro to perform three actions.
- Then attach the macro to a command button on a form

The actions are below

- Go to record- Next
- Go to record- previous
- Open form( enter name of form)-this will have parameter

Find attached an image of a sample macro

[image: macro image]

Though i will suggest you use a **One to many table instead**

The table with opening and closing times will be a foreign table
The venue table will be the primary table

Then create a parent and subform that links the two tables.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by creating linked forms using the form wizard, and then adding code to the toggle button that means the data that is input into the first form, is saved, and then you navigate to the linked form and enter the opening times?